# java.lang.NullPointerException on Iterator with HashMap

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, iterator, hashmap

I got a method to search for Clients through his ID's. It's something like this:

```
public Client searchClient(String id)
{        
    Client client=new Client();
    Iterator iter=this.getMapClient().values().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        client=(Client) iter.next();
        if(client.getId().equals(id))
        {
            return client;
        }
    }
    return client;
}
```

But I'm getting the **java.lang.NullPointerException** on this line:

```
if(cliente.getId().equals(id))
```

The Client I'm searching exists in the HashMap so I don't know why I'm getting this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something is null.  Use the debugger to determine what.

Comment: client is a good bet to be null.

Comment: Or `client.getRut()`...

Comment: I thought the same, but the iterator is assigning the values, so it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Time to use a debugger and find the point of departure from 'should' to the actual state of affairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suspect the client has a null id.  Try reversing it to 
`if(id.equals(client.getId()))`

Comment: That was the problem. That help me realize that I was saving the new Clients with all null fields, because of a problem in the data saving code. Thanks.